# How prove $S_{k}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^k_{i}$ this System of equations The only solution?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

> when I read a china book,I see this follow interesting problem (the author says it is clear have follow)
>
> if give the  number $S_{k}(x),k=1,2,3,\cdots,n$ ,and such
>   $$\begin{cases}
> S_{1}(x)=x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}\\
> S_{2}(x)=x^2_{1}+x^2_{2}+\cdots+x^2_{n}\\
> S_{3}(x)=x^3_{1}+x^3_{2}+\cdots+x^3_{n}\\
> \cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\\
> S_{n}(x)=x^n_{1}+x^n_{2}+\cdots+x^n_{n}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> show that:
>
> this system of equations has a unique solution.

we define $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})=(1,2,3),(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})=(2,3,1),(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})=(1,3,2),\cdots$ is same solution

why it is clear?

can you someone can  prove this?Thank you

Comment: What is the solution? Your post is woefully missing details.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show that the system admits only one solution $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ up to the order of the $x_i$'s?

Comment: @Crostul,yes,That's mean

Comment: Relevant AoPS Wiki article: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Newton's_Sums

Comment: This follows directly from the theory of symmetric polynomials.

Comment: The multiset $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ is uniquely determined (it is precisely the multiset of roots of a certain polynomial a la Vieta's formulas), but of course there is no canonical ordering.